# Grouping datapoint based on defined thresold values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, group-by

I have a set of 100 points column-wise. I would like to pair these data points which are within the distance threshold of -5 and 5. And, then label them accordingly by the same letters, say, A, B, C, or so on.
For example, let us assume `x` is a variable which records 100 data points and samples of them are as follows the data points

```
x=[2,5,10,13,20,25]
```

If I want to group and label them based on a defined threshold distance (here is either +5 or -5). Then I should get output something like this

```
[(2,5),(10,13),(5,10),(20,25)] and so on

A=(2,5); B=(10,13), and so on
```

The data point may include decimal points and I would like to do this in an efficient way. Any I idea how to this? Thanks in advance

Comment: First generate all possible pairs, then filter only those that meet your criterion.

Comment: Any example, how to do this?